# Get more than one stream of a YouTube channel

Tags: python, python-3.x, youtube, streamlink

So, I'm trying to get multiple live streams of a channel on YouTube and as it seems, streamlink is not capable to do so.

I tried to get all streams with `streams = streamlink.streams(URL)`, but it just returns the first live stream. Even, when there is a second

What I want is, to get URLs to all streams, when there is more than one available.